# Veins simulation terminates calling openssl ECDSA_SIG_get0 function

Tags: c++, openssl, omnet++, veins, ecdsa

I am using the virtual machine `instant-veins-4-7-1-i1` on VirtualBox with `Omnet++-5.3` and `Sumo-0.32.0`.

I have installed the library `openssl` version 1.1.0. When I try to access to the struct `ECDSA_SIG` that store the signature with the function `ECDSA_SIG_get0` the simulation terminate suddenly with the following error

[image]

This is a snippet of the code that generate the error:

```
ECDSA_SIG * signed_hash;
s->generateSignature(message, messageLength, signed_hash);
const BIGNUM **pr;
const BIGNUM **ps;
ECDSA_SIG_get0(signed_hash, pr, ps);
```

The `generateSignature` function code is:

```
void SignatureOpenSSL::generateSignature(const unsigned char* message, int messageLength, ECDSA_SIG * signed_hash)
{

    unsigned char *md;
    unsigned char *hash;
    hash = SHA256(message, messageLength, md);

    // Computes the ECDSA signature of the given message using the supplied private key and returns the created signature
    signed_hash = ECDSA_do_sign(hash, 32, eckey);

    if (signed_hash == NULL){
        std::cout <<" ko signature " << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout <<" ok signature" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

I have upgraded the `openssl` library to version 1.1.1 but the error keeps occurring.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with openssl, but your "C" code and your misuse of pointers.

Your problem line is:

```
signed_hash = ECDSA_do_sign(hash, 32, eckey);
```

Your code assumes it's changing the pointer in the calling function, it is not.  It's only changing the "copy" of the pointer.  You want to either return the pointer or pass in a pointer to a pointer and set it that way.

e.g.

```
ECDSA_SIG *SignatureOpenSSL::generateSignature(const unsigned char* message, int messageLength)
{
    ...
    ECDSA_SIG *  signed_hash = ECDSA_do_sign(hash, 32, eckey);
    ...
    return signed_hash;
}


ECDSA_SIG * signed_hash = s->generateSignature(message, messageLength);
```

or

```
void SignatureOpenSSL::generateSignature(const unsigned char* message, int messageLength, ECDSA_SIG ** signed_hash)
{
    ...
    *signed_hash = ECDSA_do_sign(hash, 32, eckey);

    if (*signed_hash == NULL){
        std::cout <<" ko signature " << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout <<" ok signature" << std::endl;
    }
}

ECDSA_SIG * signed_hash;
s->generateSignature(message, messageLength, &signed_hash);
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the second solution. In this case the correct way to call the function `ECDSA_SIG_get0` is `ECDSA_SIG_get0(signed_hash, &pr, &ps);`. Right?